# Too many open files (sockets) in Play 2.2 framework

Tags: java, ajax, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm currently on Play 2.2.1 and after running a production web app during the day, I start getting the following error in my logs. It seems like I'm running out of connections/I must not be closing something correctly, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

```
2014-02-11 18:19:24,660 - [ERROR] - from play in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31 
Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

2014-02-11 18:19:24,664 - [ERROR] - from application in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-31 


! @6h8a5lf50 - Internal server error, for (POST) [/ws-tester/ajaxProcessInput?env=development&token=XXX&dataType=xml] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files]]
at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:257) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:344) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:343) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$1.execute(Execution.scala:43) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$2.execute(Execution.scala:70) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$$anon$2.execute(Execution.scala:70) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.10-2.2.1.jar:2.2.1]
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.10-2.2.0.jar:2.2.0]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKFuture.get(JDKFuture.java:143) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKFuture.get(JDKFuture.java:118) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(execution.scala:50) ~[net.databinder.dispatch.dispatch-core_2.10-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(execution.scala:50) ~[net.databinder.dispatch.dispatch-core_2.10-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at dispatch.HttpExecutor$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(execution.scala:50) ~[net.databinder.dispatch.dispatch-core_2.10-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at dispatch.package$$anon$1.run(package.scala:18) ~[net.databinder.dispatch.dispatch-core_2.10-0.11.0.jar:0.11.0]
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.3.jar:na]
... 4 common frames omitted
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
at java.net.Socket.createImpl(Socket.java:414) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:544) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:169) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:409) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:530) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:289) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:346) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:914) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:979) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpUrlConnection.configure(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:577) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
at com.ning.http.client.providers.jdk.JDKAsyncHttpProvider$AsyncHttpUrlConnection.call(JDKAsyncHttpProvider.java:238) ~[com.ning.async-http-client-1.7.18.jar:na]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636) ~[na:1.6.0_18]
```

The primary page still displays, but the app fails on AJAX calls. The Ajax function is fairly simple:

```
def ajaxProcessInput(env : String, token : String , data : String, dataType : String)  = Action {

dataType.toLowerCase() match {
  case "csv" => {
    val a = CSVObject(CSV.parse(data))

    Ok(views.html.ajaxProvisioningResponse("(Not implemented yet) :: " + a.toString()))
  }
  case "xml" => {
    ProvisioningServiceHandler.provision(environments.get(env),token = Base64Binary(token),data) match {
      case Right(result) => { Ok(views.html.ajaxProvisioningResponse(result.resultData.getOrElse("No Result"))) }
      case Left(error) => { InternalServerError(views.html.ajaxSOAPFault(error)) }
    }
  }
  case _ => Ok("Invalid Data Type")
}
}
```

I call it using this piece of Coffee Script:

```
process = (entry,type) ->
  jsRoutes.controllers.ServiceProvisioner.ajaxProcessInput($('#environment').find('option:selected').val(), $('#authToken').text(), $(entry).val(),type).ajax
    success: (rr) ->
       $('#provResponse').html rr
    error: (rr) ->
       $('#provResponse').html rr.responseText

$("#processCSV").click ->
  process '#csvEntry','csv'

$("#processXML").click ->
  process '#xmlEntry','xml'
```

and in case it matters, here is how I generate my Javascript routes:

```
def jsRoutes = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(
    Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")
    (routes.javascript.ServiceProvisioner.ajaxAuthToken,
     routes.javascript.ServiceProvisioner.ajaxProcessInput)
  ).as("text/javascript")
}
```

Here are the actual routes:

```
POST        /ajaxProcessInput           controllers.ServiceProvisioner.ajaxProcessInput(env : String, token : String , data : String, dataType : String)
GET         /jsRoutes                   controllers.ServiceProvisioner.jsRoutes
```

And I include them in my HTML view like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.ServiceProvisioner.jsRoutes"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the stack trace, you're using the dispatch HTTP client.  I would guess that every time you're using it, you're creating a new instance of the dispatch client, and that the dispatch client is starting up thread pools and connection pools, and then you're never shutting them down, hence the resource leak.

Either shutdown the client after each usage, or use a singleton client.  You can also use Play's WS client instead of using dispatch, Play manages its lifecycle so that you don't have to.

Comment: How would I use scalaxb with Play's WS client? I'd assume I'd replace the DispatcHttpClient with a class from play.api.libs.ws? I tried searching but couldn't find any examples.

Comment: Found where I was creating my SOAP clients and changed it to a lazy val pattern to reuse them; fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: lazy val might work fine for your app in production, but it will probably cause problems in development, every time your app reloads, those threads won't be shutdown, and so you'll have the same leak.  It's best to create it when Play starts and shut it down when Play stops, you can do this in Global, or by implementing the Plugin interface.